# "can't write unknown attribute"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I run as my textbook says, but error occurs.
 It's a book management application.

**What I want to run**

```
irb(main):001:0>publisher = Publisher.create name: 'Gihyo inc.', address: 'Ichigaya'
irb(main):002:0>publisher.books << Book.find(1)
irb(main):003:0>publisher.books.to_a
```

**result**

First,

```
irb(main):001:0>publisher = Publisher.create name: 'Gihyo inc.', address: 'Ichigaya'
```

seems succeeded.

Next,

```
irb(main):002:0>publisher.books << Book.find(1)
```

failed.

The result is as follows.

```
 Book Load(0.6ms) SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]]
  (4.0ms) begin transaction
  (0.3ms) rollback transaction
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `publisher_id'
   from ...
```

**related models**

*book.rb*

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :costly, ->{where("price>?" ,3000) }

 belongs_to :publisher
end
```

*publisher.rb*

```
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :books
end
```

**related migrations**

*20141218113551_create_publishers.rb*

```
class CreatePublishers < ActiveRecord ::Migration
 def change
  create_table :publishers do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.text :address

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

*20141218113811_add_publisher_id_to_books.rb*

```
class AddPublisherIdToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  add_reference :books, :publisher, index: true
 end
end
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you run your migration?

Comment: did you run the migrations?

Comment: I ran migration once and if now I run `./bin/rake db:migrate`, he says error and something like `"table publishers" already exists`.

Comment: it happens when you have messed up the migration files (e.g. you have 2 migrations, which create same table)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error after changing -

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :true
```

to this - `belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true`

Notice the boolean, I was using as a symbol...which was totally incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It actually means, that you have no such field in database.

Checking your migration will help with this issue.